# Ajax не возвращает переменную

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

есть код:
js:

```
fd.append('img', $('.cool_inp').prop('files')[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'sender.php',
                    data: fd,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: successSave
                });
```

php:

```
<?
 $img = $_FILES['img'];
 $name_dir = date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); 
 mkdir('clients/'.$name_dir);
 $string_src = 'clients/'.$name_dir.'/'.$img['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'], $string_src); //работает
 echo  $string_src;
?>
```

и success:

```
 function successSave(data){
      $('#prev').css('background', 'url(' + data + ') no-repeat');
   }
```

не понимаю в чем ошибка - когда в echo просто текст - выводит ссылку, как только любая переменная - не выводит вообще ничего

Comment: Если стиля не видно в инспекторе попробуйте рассинхронить ajax `$.ajax({async:false...});`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас имя картинки русское, попробуйте сделать так:

```
$img = $_FILES['img'];
$name_dir = date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); 
mkdir('clients/'.$name_dir);
$string_src = 'clients/'.$name_dir.'/'.$img['name'];
move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'], $string_src); //работает
echo  iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $string_src);
```

Comment: проверил по другому - в alert выводит всё как надо, а вот на background url - не заменяет вообще

Comment: $('#prev').css('background-image', 'url(' + data + ')');